# Process raw HTTP request

Tags: http, curl

I'd like to pass a raw HTTP request like:

```
GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; fr; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://example.org/test
Cookie: foo=bar; lorem=ipsum;
```

to a HTTP client.

I tried `cat raw.http | curl` but without success.

Any suggestion?

Thx.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Raw data in, raw data out:

```
nc example.org 80 < raw.http
```

If you need to pipe the data through some program:

```
cat raw.http | someprogram | nc example.org 80
```

[Manual page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/nc/)

Comment: this is a deceptively simple answer. It only works in some cases. i have used this and socat. If the server responds with chunked encoding you will only get the first response, which may be blank.  I came here looking for a correct answer which I can't find anywhere!

Comment: @sillyMunky If you have a new question to ask, please use the Ask Question button above. By *First response*, do you mean the first chunk or the first reply to a request (with `Connection: Keep-Alive`)?

Comment: this doesnt do anything for me. hangs for ages and finally displays nothing, not even an error.

Comment: @Blauhirn You have likely forgotten the blank line at the end of the headers. Example: `printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n' | nc example.com 80`

Comment: What can be a reason when I obtain 499 status code from nc?

Comment: @MichalS. 499 is not a standardized code. Based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes, one possible explanation is 499 Client Closed Request which is sent by nginx when "the client has closed the request before the server could send a response".

Comment: To make it work I've had to add two empty lines at the end of raw request

Answer (score 18):

The question is tagged curl so I thought it was about time there was a curl answer

```
cat raw.http | curl "telnet://TARGETHOST:80"
```

For normal use just need to set the TARGETHOST to be the same as "host" header value.

For my purposes(not normal) I was hitting a TARGETHOST that was an ip address with a server that was listening for host headers of specific hosts.

Comment: Also, with this solution you can use https :443.

Comment: Unlike the nc option, this correctly handled my request ,which included an "Expect: 100-continue" header. Remember to do "Ctrl-]", then "quit", to exit telnet.

Answer (score 16):

Note that neither of these solutions would work if your need httpS instead of http. In this case you can send it this way:

```
$ cat raw.http | openssl s_client -connect server:443
```

Comment: How do you see the response sent back from the server in this case?

Comment: To see the response you have to pass `-ign_eof` (or `-quiet` which enables that) to make the client to wait for the response before closing the connection. And check https://serverfault.com/q/731232/58957 if you expect the command to quit after receiving the response.

Comment: `cat raw.http | ncat --ssl host 443` should work too. (ncat from nmap package)