# Apache Access Log request that does not start with a forward slash /

Tags: apache, http, url

I came across an IP address / unknown bot that made four HTTP requests, managing to request four different domain names in the following fashion *without* the first character being a forward slash /:

```
"GET www.example.com
```

When I make test the request `http://localhost/www.example.com` I see the following in Apache:

```
"GET /www.example.com
```

All other requests start with a forward slash. How did the bot manage to make such a request and how can I reproduce this to determine how to handle such requests?

Quoted Apache logs reduced to request method and URL to avoid off-topic comments.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way [HTTP requests](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) work, this can be achieved by sending a raw HTTP request to your IP address and specifying both the `GET` and `Host` headers as described on the linked page above:

> The most common form of Request-URI is that used to identify a
> resource on an origin server or gateway. In this case the absolute
> path of the URI MUST be transmitted (see section 3.2.1, abs_path) as
> the Request-URI, and the network location of the URI (authority) MUST
> be transmitted in a Host header field. For example, a client wishing
> to retrieve the resource above directly from the origin server would
> create a TCP connection to port 80 of the host "www.w3.org" and send
> the lines:
>
> ```
>    GET /pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
>    Host: www.w3.org
> ```
>
> followed by the remainder of the Request. Note that the absolute path cannot be empty; if none is present in the
> original URI, it MUST be given as "/" (the server root).

This can be done on Windows using PuTTY, or on Linux/Mac using `nc` (see answer here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3620596/1038813)

Comment: Nice, this is more of a nice-to-have for me so after I take care of some other stuff I'll review this properly and officially accept it. Thank you!

Comment: So, using cURL, how do I specify the host and separately specify the relative URL? I should have tagged my question with cURL...

Comment: With cURL you have to create a text file containing the request headers (or echo it) and then pipe it to cURL using `telnet://TARGETHOST:80` as the URL: `cat raw.http | curl "telnet://TARGETHOST:80"`